# Why has my question been left closed for 3 years with no feedback?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

In 2016 I asked this question:

[C++ constexpr math (header-only) library](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/29974/c-constexpr-math-header-only-library)

it was closed as lacking details or clarity. The comment was:

> Need details of which platform, CPU, OS, etc., to possibly answer.

I explained why a constexpr header-only library is by definition irrespective of these details; and I also edited to clarify that the library must be fully cross-platform (which any constexpr functionality library would have to be actually). Other commenters also chimed in, saying that the question was perfectly clear.

Still, 4 years have passed and the question has not been reopened. I have answers I wish to add - but cannot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this to our community's attention.

I just took a look at the question, and I see no reason that it cannot be reopened, so I reopened it for you and the community.

Several community members (including myself before I was elected as a moderator) voted for it to be re-opened in the past, but we didn't meet StackExchange's required number of voters to reopen it.  After some time passed, our reopen votes aged away (I personally don't like that "feature" of the StackExchange network).

I look forward to reading your answers, as I'm sure others do as well!

Comment: Thanks. Two answers are up.

Comment: @einpoklum You're welcome.  Glad to help.  Your answers look great.

Comment: I will just add that the reopen reviews can be found both [in the timeline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/29974/timeline) and [using SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/softwarerecs/query/1086014/list-of-reviews-for-a-specific-post?postid=29974).

Comment: " our reopen votes aged away (I personally don't like that "feature" of the StackExchange network)." +1, makes no sense.